# Mocking default values of attr.ib()

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, python-attrs

I have a situation similar to the following

```
@attrs(auto_attribs=True)
class ExampleClass:
  _prop: OtherClass = attrib(init=False, default=OtherClass())
  def some_func(self):
    test_var = OtherClass()
    test_var.some_func()
    self._prop.some_func()

class OtherClass:
  def some_func(self):
    raise NotImplementedException

def test_example(mocker):
  mocker.patch("path.to.example_class.OtherClass")
  sut = ExampleClass()
  sut.some_func()
```

All of the classes and tests are in different files and the mocker is a fixture provided by pytest_mock that is just a wrapper around unittest.mock that takes care of cleanup easier.

The issue I run into is that when running the unit tests, test_var is getting correctly assigned as a MagicMock from the patch function. So when test_var.some_func() is returned everything is fine.

When `self._prop.some_func()` is being called, the `NotImplementedException` is getting raised as it appears that the patch is not impacting this.

In my unit test, I could set `sut._prop = MagicMock()` but this is an internal implementation detail making it a fragile test.

How does one go about mocking the default variable in the attrib to avoid this?

Comment: Because `default=OtherClass()` will be executed on module import and `mocker.patch('modname.Class')` will import the module before patching, the default `OtherClass` instance will be already initialized when `mocker` does its job. This is tricky to avoid. If `OtherClass` is in `spam.py` and `ExampleClass` in `eggs.py`, then the ordering `mocker.patch('spam.OtherClass'); import eggs; eggs.ExampleClass().some_func()` should work, but if both classes are in the same module, I don't see a way beside monkeypatching the `default` instance in `ExampleClass.__attrs_attrs__`.

Comment: Thanks, you triggered me to do some more digging and realized I was using the library wrong in I was setting the default as an instance and I wanted a new instance every time and that wouldn't be happening. Using a lambda I was able to get my result and have testing working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the library functionally incorrectly as I was setting the default to an instance when I wanted a new instance every time. Changing the ExampleClass to the following fixes my issue

```
@attrs(auto_attribs=True)
class ExampleClass:
  _prop: OtherClass = attrib(init=False, factory=lambda: OtherClass())
  def some_func(self):
    test_var = OtherClass()
    test_var.some_func()
    self._prop.some_func()
```

Comment: `factory=lambda: OtherClass()` is unnecessarily complicated; just go for `factory=OtherClass` as long as it doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: One of my classes does that arguments. But also the patching wasn't working when you do factory=OtherClass. I believe this is due to creating an instance of the factory and then patching can't be applied while with the lambda it is called every time.